# How to solve the problem 'zsh: command not found: jupyter'

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I bought Macbook air M1, and I tried to install jupyter notebook with this code.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip

pip3 install jupyter
```

and I tried to open jupyter notebook with this code.

```
jupyter notebook
```

but, then, this code appeared.

```
zsh: command not found: jupyter
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLQGX.png)

Comment: try `pip3 show jupyter`

Comment: Run `pip3 install jupyter` again, and add its output to the question.

Answer (score 11):

First, you need to find where it was installed.

```
pip3 show jupyter | grep Location
```

Example:

```
$ pip3 show pip | grep Location

Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Then you need to ensure that the path you get is in your PATH.

Example:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:$PATH
```

Comment: I finally solved this problem with your help! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Soojoo If this solves your problem, it is a good practice to accept the answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Python's `bin/` folder path to `$PATH` variable.
You should be able to find it here - `/Users/<your-username>/Library/Python/3.x/bin`

Step 1 : Open .bash_profile in text editor

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Step 2 : Add the following line at the end of the file

```
export PATH="/Users/<your-username>/Library/Python/3.x/bin:$PATH"
```

Step 3 : Save the edits made to .bash_profile and restart the terminal

Answer (score 0):

This issue and many others are bound to happen with Jupyter. There are many tools that install Jupyter and they all do it a bit differently.

To sidestep the whole problem of clunky installs, try a desktop "click and run" app for Jupyter.

For macOS and iOS, that's [Callisto](https://callistoapp.com). It's currently in the beta stage so you can try it out for free (it even lets you connect to cloud servers for running your notebooks!)

For reference: This [comment](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/317#issuecomment-371542637) has a good solution for fixing pip3 install on macOS

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Updating ~/.bash_profile didn't work for me. I printed the PATH variable using

`echo $PATH` and it didn't print the added directories to bash_profile.

My problem was solved after I added the directories in `.zprofile`. Currently, its contents are

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
export PATH="/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH"
```

Both `.zprofile` and `.bash_profile` locations are in the following directory.

```
"/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/"
```

It maybe hidden and to reveal it press `command+shift+.`